# Choosing from two instances of the same form in Django post-request

Tags: django

I have the following issue best described by example.

First, I send two instances of the same form to a Django template.

View 1:

```
def view_1
leg_address_form = AddressForm()
fct_address_form = AddressForm()
return render_to_response('my_template.html',
                          {'leg_address_form':leg_address_form,
                           'fct_address_form':fct_address_form},...
```

After this, when submit button is pressed somewhere in my_template, I have to process the request and I am having trouble accessing the data from the two form instances.

View 2:

```
def employee_create(request.POST):
    leg_address_form = AddressForm(request.POST) #how could I know which one is it?
    fct_address_form = AddressForm(request.POST) #how could I know which one is it?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [prefix](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms) to give each Form its own namespace.

```
def main_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        leg_address_form = AddressForm(request.POST, prefix='leg')
        fct_address_form = AddressForm(request.POST, prefix='fct')
        # do something with data
    else:
        leg_address_form = AddressForm(prefix="leg")
        fct_address_form = AddressForm(prefix="fct")
    return render_to_response('my_template.html',
                      {'leg_address_form':leg_address_form,
                       'fct_address_form':fct_address_form},...
```

Comment: I updated my answer. Here I just use only one view function.